# TreeMap put not adding

Tags: java, treemap

I am trying to make a TreeMap sort neural networks with their fitnesses. Here is my code to do so.

```
private double[][] sort(){
    double[][] populationFitnesses = new double[populationNumber][populationSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < populationSize; i++) {
        NeuralNetwork[] networks = allInIndex(i);
        double[] fitnesses = fitness(networks);
        for (int j = 0; j < populationNumber; j++) {
            populationFitnesses[j][i] = fitnesses[j];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < populationNumber; i++) {

        Map<Double, NeuralNetwork> sorted = new TreeMap<>();

        for (int j = 0; j < populationSize; j++) {
            System.out.println(sorted.size());
            sorted.put(populationFitnesses[i][j], populations[i][j]);
            System.out.println(sorted.size());
        }

        ArrayList<Double> keys = new ArrayList<>(sorted.keySet());

        for (int j = 0; j < populationSize; j++) {
            populations[i][j] = sorted.get(keys.get(j));
            populationFitnesses[i][j] = keys.get(j);
        }
    }
    return populationFitnesses;
}
```

For some reason, when I call TreeMap.put, it doesn't seem to be adding anything to it. Could someone please explain how to fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: Well, where do you initialize `populationFitness`? Can you print that field out and verify that it does have data in it? (Use `Arrays.deepToString()`).

Comment: I added the rest of the code for the sort() method

Comment: Arrays.deepToString returns all the information in the array.

Comment: Which, is how many rows and columns, for those of us who are still trying to guess.

Comment: *it doesn't seem to be adding anything to it*. Why do you think so? What is the input and the output allowing to make that claim?

Comment: The output for sorted.size before and after adding an element to the map is 1

Comment: So that means you're trying to add the same key again. put will only increase the size of the map if the second key is different.